# How to make Juddery Simulation of Falling Leaves smooth?

Tags: particles, physics, collision, force-fields

I am using a particle system and a force field to simulate falling leaves. The leaves are falling from the sky and are supposed to stay on the ground. I encounter two problems here:

1. The falling motion is very jerky and unnatural. How can I make the falling motion smoother?
2. The leaves get stuck sideways in the ground and jerk around like crazy. I want the leaves to just stay on the ground.

[Blend File](https://we.tl/t-Y57ZN85n2i)

Comment: Hi Christoph, i would recommend using rigid bodies or cloth simulation for that. If you want to use particles, you should tap on "make instances real" and then give them rigid bodies or cloth modifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this result by adding a ground plane with collision, adding a plane as emitter with object a subdivided plane.

Then I tapped the "make instances real" button on the emitter and hid my emitter in render + viewport. Then I moved all my leaves to a collection called leaves. Then I added cloth to all that instances.
Add some wind and turbulence and it looked like this:

[image]

[image]

Note: to run the blend file you have to change the simulation end to 250 for the leaves and for the animation. (I had to delete the bake because the file was too big )

[image]

Comment: oh man... this looks SO MUCH better! Thanks!!!

Comment: You are welcome!!